# Case when first instance of unique ID

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm in Snowflake and am trying to mark the first occurrence of a unique ID in a column. I've been playing around with first_value but am not really getting anywhere.

So my data looks something like this:

```
ID Date
123 1/2019
123 2/2019
123 3/2019
234 2/2019
234 3/2019
```

And ideally I want something like this:

```
ID Date    First?
123 1/2019 1
123 2/2019 0
123 3/2019 0
234 2/2019 1
234 3/2019 0
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

You want `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT 
   ID, 
   Date, 
   IFF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) = 1, 1, 0) AS First
FROM 
   schema.table
ORDER BY ID, Date
;
```

This checks whether the current row is the first date for the ID, and if it is, assigns a value of 1 (otherwise 0).

Comment: This is pretty great! Thank you for your help, if you are interested the Snowflake Community has  Select Star program that adds points to your profile if you are a register Snowflake user, check out the page and sign up if you are interested: https://community.snowflake.com/s/selectstar

Answer (score 1):

[`LAG`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) can also be used to solve this..

```
SELECT id
    ,date
    ,lag(id) over (partition by id order by date) is null as first
FROM table_name;
```

Which can be also done with [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) like

```
SELECT id
    ,date
    ,first_value(id) over (partition by id order by date) = date as first
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to retrieve the first occurrence of a unique ID in a column then the row_number() or the dense_rank() function can help.

---

```
with cte as
(
select ID, Date,
row_number() over (partition by ID order by date) as row_number
from table1
)
select * from cte where row_number = 1;
```

---

```
with cte as
(
select ID, Date,
dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by date) as rank
from stack1
)
select * from cte where rank = 1;
```